# Redirection Operators: two cases

Tags: linux, bash, operators, stdout, stdin

Consider the following command line:

```
cat <<< "Hello World" > output1.txt > output2.txt ... > outputn.txt
```

In this case we have `<<<` here-string operator, which is an input redirection operator. But let's focus on `> output redirection operator`. It works perfectly, sending channels from cat command output (stdout) to different files output1.txt, output2.txt etc.

Now consider the command line below:

```
cat < input1.txt < input2.txt ...  < inputn.txt
```

Similarly to what occurs in the first command line with `> output redirection operators`, I expected each `< input redirection operator` sending the files contents to `cat command stdin`. But instead, cat is catching only the last file content (inputn.txt) ignoring the rest.

Is cat command ignoring `<` before inputn.txt and reading it as an `argument` (which is preferred to `stdin`)? Or inputn.txt was sent to `stdin`? In this case, why are input1.txt, input2.txt... contents not in `stdin` stream of cat command?

Comment: bash doesn't do what you describe on output either; content will only go to the file in the last redirect (basically, each redirect replaces any previous conflicting redirect). zsh *does* support multiple redirections with its `MULTIOS` option. In bash, you need to pipe through `tee` to replicate output to multiple target files, and `cat` to read from multiple input files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash processes redirections left-to-right on the command line *before* running the process.  Each redirection is self-contained and will redirect a file descriptor to/from the file, so if you have multiple redirects that affect the *same* file descriptor, only the last one will (still) be in effect when the command runs.

So in your output case

```
cat <<< "Hello World" > output1.txt > output2.txt ... > outputn.txt
```

The output files `output1.txt`, `output2.txt` etc will be created but stdout will be left pointing at the last one (`outputn.txt`) and all the output of cat will go there and the other files will be empty.

Similarly with the input case

```
cat < input1.txt < input2.txt ...  < inputn.txt
```

each file will be opened, but stdin will be left pointing at the last one, so nothing will be read from the others.